# Fixed Headers and Section Anchors with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I swear I have tried everything that I can think of to solve this issue. I have a fixed bootstrap navbar, using a javascript onscroll event listener to apply the fixed attribute...I tried using style in the markup, but it did not have the desired effect.  So of course this is a repetitive issue, but I have tried all the recommendations and then some. At least all that I could find. The problem is that when I use any #about internal link, the content falls beneath the navbar. I have tried margins, absolute, relative, top -...px on .section2. None of it worked.

And please I am new to this, so any solutions, please make it specific to my code and not just add a position to the anchor. Give me the exact class/id and what to add, or remove, or both.
here is a link to the live page to see what happens when you click any link for #about section: [portfolio #about](https://kingdomb.github.io/live_portfolio/#about)

https://kingdomb.github.io/live_portfolio/#about

NOTE: The code below does not give display the error properly so use the link above.

UPDATE: 3/22 02:16
I managed to find this:

```
Come on guys!
```

This have a very simple solution, create your ancho like this:

```
<div style="margin: -50px 0px 50px 0px; position: absolute;">
<a id="myanchor"></a>
</div>
```

With -50px margin what i make is upper the anchor div, and with 50px margin, i push down the next content. You only have to make your test with your custom margins.

Works like a charm. I use this trick in all one page design websites.

BUT, now one click on the about link in the navbar to #myanchor gives me this:[image: correct position]

And if I click the exact same navbar link I get a minor adjustment to this:[image: incorrect position]

THANKS!!!

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
  myFunction2();
};

// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll 
position.Remove "sticky"
when you leave the scroll position

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

// Get the logo
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

// Get the offset position of the logo
var logoSpin = logo.offsetTop;

// Add the logo-spin class to the navbar when you reach its scroll 
position.Remove "logo-spin"
when you leave the scroll position

function myFunction2() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= logoSpin) {
    logo.classList.add("logo-spin");
  } else {
    logo.classList.remove("logo-spin");
  }
}

// All links will have a target:__blank for external page linking
// Read more: https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#ixzz6GMsDfQEr
// jQuery(document.links)
//   .filter(function() {
//     return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
//   })
//   .attr("target", "_blank");

//OR Read more: https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#ixzz6GN6pd1Qt
function externalLinks() {
  for (var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0; a <
    c.length; a++) {
    var b = c[a];
    b.getAttribute("href") &&
      b.hostname !== location.hostname &&
      (b.target = "_blank");
  }
}
externalLinks();
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* HOME */

.section1 {
  background: url("../images/laptop-table1920-gray.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section1 .container {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-color: #8e0000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #8e0000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 1.12em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: .1px .8px 1px black;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}


/* hover styling required !important */

.home-btn:hover {
  color: #8e0000 !important;
  border-color: #8e0000;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-width: 3px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: .1px 2px 1px black;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

.intro {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.74em;
  text-shadow: .1px .8px 1px black;
}

.highlight {
  color: #8e0000;
  text-shadow: .1px .8px 1px black;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 2px 1px black;
}

.logo-spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s;
  animation: spin 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 65px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #212529;
  border-top: 6px solid #212529;
}

#navbar {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .navbar-text {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 1px 1px black;
}


/* ABOUT */

#about {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-shadow: .1px .8px 1px black;
  position: relative;
  height: -65px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}


/* .section2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

} */

.section2 .row {
  background: url("../images/improved-teamwork-and- 
 collaboration_1887x741.jpg") center center no-repeat;
 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.section2 .card {
  background-color: RGBA(33, 37, 41, .80);
  color: white;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: 100%;
}

.section2 .card-block {
  font-weight: 520;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 60px;
}

.section2 a {
  color: #9b0000;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(.1px .8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

.section2 .card-block {
  z-index: 8000;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.section2 a:hover,
.section2 #skills:hover,
.section2 #projects:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.section2 .btn {
  border-color: #8e0000;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border-width: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease- in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in- out;
}

.section2 .btn:hover {
  background-color: #8e0000;
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#about {
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- HOME -->
  <section id="home" class="section1">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <p class='intro'>
            Hello, my name is <span class="highlight animated fadeIn" style="animation-delay:             1s; animation-duration: 
1.8s">King</span>.
            <br>
            <div class="intro animated fadeInLeft" style="animation- 
delay: 3s; animation-                 duration: 2s">And I'm a full- stack web developer.</div>
            <a href="#myanchor"><button type="button" class="home-btn 
btn btn-primary-outline                btn-xs animated fadeIn"
             style="animation-delay: 5s; animation-duration: 
2s">VIEW MY WORK</button></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-wrapper nav-item active">
          <div class="logo" id="logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="favicon.ico" alt="King's Brand                 Logo"></a>
          </div>
          <span class="brand" id="brand" style="animation-delay: 0s; 
animation-duration:                 3s">KING MAJOR</span>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor">ABOUT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">SKILLS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">PROJECTS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <!-- ABOUT -->
  <div class="blank" style="margin: -65px 0px 200px 0px; position: 
absolute;">
    <a id="myanchor"></a>
  </div>
  <section id="about" class="section2">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h1>Welcome, <a href="#">let's talk!</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
              <p> I started independent web development two years ago, and haven't looked back. A couple of things I love about coding are those moments when tough projects are complete, or discovering a solution to a difficult problem. Take a look at my
                <a href="#skills">skills</a>, and some of my recent
                <a href="#projects">projects</a>. THANKS!
              </p>
              <a href="General_Resume.pdf" class="btn btn-outline- 
    primary" target="__blank">Print My Resume
            </a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found this but no luck for me. The #about section just ends up ovelapping the #skills section and sometimes the #about section just get closer to the top of the home section. 
This is CSS “nightmare” - no way to solve this without some “TRICKS” (I hope webflow will add “from-top” option for anchor links). The most simple solution (You’ll find smarter solutions): Create empty div (Put ID for this div) - position: relative; and minus the height of the nav: [image] [im…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I refactored the code in the ABOUT section to this:

```html
<!-- ABOUT -->
<div class="blank" style="position: absolute">
  <a id="myanchor"></a>
</div>
<section id="about" class="section2">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h1>Welcome, <a href="#">let's talk!</a></h1>
          </div>
          <div id="container">
            <p> I started independent web development two years ago, and haven't looked back. A              couple of things I love about coding are those moments when tough projects are                  complete, or discovering a solution to a difficult problem. Take a look at my
              <a href="#skills">skills</a>, and some of my recent <a                                         href="#projects">projects</a>. THANKS!
            </p>
            <a href="General_Resume.pdf" class="btn btn-outline-primary" target="__blank">Print              My Resume</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Notice that I removed the opening div margin html styling.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having this issue is that the `.section2` section it looks like you have a `margin-top: 200px`. Therefore creating that space. Now you can just adjust accordingly.

I would be careful when using margins. Using them only if you have to. I rarely use it, only for minor tweaks and responsiveness. If you are styling correct there should be no use for margins. I would take a look into using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This is super useful when creating nice functional layouts. It's a great starter for new people too. The sooner you get into it, the easier layouts will be for you.

I also noticed that you are using javascript to add external links that open in a new page. To do that an easier way is to do something like this `<a href="someoutsidelink.com" target="_blank">`. Here is a reference, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

As for your navbar fixed, here is some code that you should use instead of the one you have now.

```
    var elementPosition = $("#navbar").offset();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $("#navbar")
        .css("position", "fixed")
        .css("top", "0");
    } else {
        $("#navbar").css("position", "static");
    }
    });
```

**Edit One:** 
 Here's one way to do this one is adding a blank `<div class="blank">` tags. Place it on top of the `<section class="section2">` opening tag. then add a `height: 200px; width: 100%` therefore creating that space.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but from what I understand, that is not the issue. please use the link I provided to view how the navbar overlaps the #about section. I actually want a space between the navbar and the #about section when I click an element that is linked to the #about section. are you seeing what I am describing?
the reason why I used js for the links is that the js grabs all <a> links and I would not have to use target="_blank" for every separate instance.

Comment: What are you trying to show in that section? Are you trying to show something or just blank space?

Comment: I am trying to have a fixed navbar with the #about section that has text and the image as a background. That section I would like to display with white space above and below for an "even" look.

Comment: Ok, that's an easy fix. I will post the solution above.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EC5IHCyOfIBhlzouAdKd8CK5cnSx95bw/view?usp=sharing

That is what I want.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately that did not do the trick. Let me remove the .sticky and see what happens then...
...removing the .sticky onscroll event listener actually made the result worse. 

You seem to be on a somewhat correct track, but if I click the about navbar link I get 2 different results

Comment: I apologize, but I am trying to learn and I would like to know what your code does. The first line of the "if" statement isn't clear to me. The rest I am sure I understand enough to figure it out with some Google-fu.

Comment: What the if statement is doing, it's using jquery, saying hey if the top positioning of the window is greater than the positioning of the #navbar element then add "fixed". So if the window onload has a starting position of `top: -800px ` compared to #navbar. When it goes past the top positioning of navbar add that fixed. No worries, you will learn. Keep on trying and learning. No doubt you will understand!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210085/discussion-between-kingdomb-and-graysonmcm).

Comment: I apologize. Not sure what happened to my code edits.